# Node.js compilation error

Tags: node.js, compilation, x86, synology

I've been trying to run a Node.js based service on my custom built Synology NAS. It is a HP N54L, running Synology DSM 4.2. Of course bootstrapped, required packages (openssl-dev, python, etcetera) are installed.

Configuration and most of the build goes fine, but then I get this error:
http://pastebin.com/KhWcVhmQ

From here I cannot go anywhere. Checked the files, the marked lines are just like the surroundings, so I do not understand the problem.

Did anyone else experience similar compile problems? If yes, could you solve it, and how?

Comment: What compiler and version are you using?

Comment: Compiler is the ipkg-downloaded gcc, make, autoconf, etc., version is the latest from git (I believe same as the packaged release, 0.10.18)